# ListView is creating new controls instead of refreshing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a control that uses a `ParentObject` as its DataContext. The `ParentObject` has a property called `ChildObject` that may change. When it does, `ParentObject` raises the PropertyChanged event.

The control has XAML to define a `ListView` for the items in the `List` property of the `ChildObject`. When the `ChildObject` property changes in the `ParentObject`, the entire view is recreated, meaning that new controls are instantiated.

The `ListView` is actually much more complicated than the example below, so recreating it is processor intensive and takes a long time.

What are my other options? Can I cache the entire `ListView` for each `ChildObject`? How would I go about doing that?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ParentObject.ChildObject.List}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Error">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:ErrorControl DataContext="{Binding ErrorCollection}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Is it the rendering that take time or creating the list take time?

Answer (score 1):

The listview is creating new controls becuase of your datatemplate. With data templates, you have a one-to-one relationship between the instance of your data and the controls inside of the datatemplate. You have a few options:

1) Have you looked into virtualization? This will only render what is visible. If you have a high number of objects, you definitely want to consider this.

2) Have you thought about re-working your view-model to minimize the change in your collections? Instead of adding/removing objects anytime an error changes. Re-use the objects in the collection and only add/remove when your total count changes.

I've done both of these to slow changes to the view from the view-model. They both improved performance significantly, but I had hundreds of objects on the screen.

Comment: My issue isn't that the collection items are changing, it is that the collection itself is changing. There are only a (relatively) few items in the collection, but the ListView used to display them is quite large (larger than the example I gave). That is why I'd like to investigate caching the entire ListView object and replacing it whenever ChildObject changes.

Comment: @ken Virtualization is what you need. Implement option 1.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I'm explaining myself very well. I actually want the opposite of virtualization: I want the entire ListView to be rendered and cached, and then swapped with other cached ListViews whenever the ChildObject property changes on the ParentObject.

Comment: Perhaps you should use multiple collections then. You could datatemplate each collection with its own listview. Honestly, I think caching large amounts of info is less performant than virtualization. Rendering is expensive. What is the percentange of items you are displaying on the screen. If it's a high percentange, maybe virtualization doesn't get you much. If it is a low percentage, virtualization is a good choice hands-down.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. I ended up doing the "caching" in code-behind. I'll post my method as an answer later.